# Linux ATI 5970 VDDC temperature reading

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amd-radeon

How to read VDDC temperature on ATI 5970 card under Linux (Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Install the 'git-core' and 'pciutils-dev' packages in Ubuntu
2. Get my fork of radeonvolt from github: https://github.com/runeksvendsen/radeonvolt by executing this command:

   ```
   git clone git://github.com/runeksvendsen/radeonvolt.git
   ```
3. The above command creates a directory called 'radeonvolt' with some source files in it. Enter the directory and build radeonvolt with the 'make' command

   ```
   cd radeonvolt
   make
   ```
4. Fire up the newly-built radeonvolt binary **as root**, and cross your fingers that your card has a Volterra VT1165 VRM chip (yes it helps crossing your fingers):

   ```
   sudo ./radeonvolt
   ```

radeonvolt is a command line program written by [ius](https://github.com/ius) to probe the Volterra VT1165 VRM chip used on some Radeon HD cards, to get VRM temperatures and set the core voltage. It was explicitly written for the reference Radeon HD 5850 cards, but people have repored success using it with 5970 cards. Whether it works with your card depends on whether the OEM that produced your card has used the above mentioned VRM chip in their design. If no non-reference 5970 cards are available (I don't know if there are) it should work, since other people have reported success using it with a 5970 before.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'VDDC', but you can read the temperature of an ATI graphics card by entering this in a terminal (while X is running):

```
aticonfig --odgt
```

which will output something like:

```
Default Adapter - ATI Radeon HD 2400 XT
              Sensor 0: Temperature - 63.00 C
```

Or use

```
aticonfig --pplib-cmd "get
```

which will output something like:

```
Temperature for thermal controller 0 is 63.000000
```

I'm not sure why a tool has two different methods for doing the same thing, but hey.

Comment: this outputs CPU temps. But I want to see VDDC temps. http://i538.photobucket.com/albums/ff342/MilesRdz/Umm.png

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that :)